# Different views for subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sti

I'm using STI subclasses and want to direct to different views for the different subclasses.  At the moment I'm routing the subclass topic to the main class article like this:

```
 resources :topics, :controller => 'articles'
```

Is there an easy way to direct to different views?

---

Edit

The best way I've found of doing this is:

```
  <% case%>
    <% when @article.type == 'Topic' %>
      <%= render 'topic' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'article' %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name your views smartly enough, you could just do

```
render @article.type
```

or

```
render :partial => @article.type
```

Otherwise you could define a method in all your STI subclasses that returns the name of the partial/page to be display, that way you'll avoid all the if/else logic in your controller.

Another approach would be to have separate controllers for the different subclasses, but that is not a good design. If you were to take such a path, than maybe STI wasn't the best approach after all.

Comment: The `type` will be a class name and views are usually lower case with underscores so `render @article.type.underscore` would be a better choice than just `@article.type`.

Comment: Thanks - the first way is very clever and what I'll probably use.  But could you give me an example or pointers for your second way - how would I write such a method?

Comment: In every sub class that you use in the STI you could define a method say 'partial_to_render', and calling this on the object will return the name of the partial. You could even declare this method in the parent class - in case the method is not defined to in one of the subclass (this could be your default page to render). And thanks mu for the correction.

Comment: Object.type is deprecated user Object.class :)