# Different view depending on Model's subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, sti

In my Rails 3.2 application I have a model that has two subclasses, and follows the STI approach:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class House < Building
end

class Apartment < Building
end
```

The only controller I have, is the one for the main model (`Building`) and would like it to keep like this. In the views, how would you render instances of different subclasses in case its representation is different? I thought about checking the model's type and rendering a template depending on it, but this is not really scalable in case I wanted to add new subclasses.

Comment: Hi @davids, just grappling with this myself :) Is this relevant/helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692980/different-views-for-subclasses?rq=1